# How can I click on the third element in this list using selenium? I have tried everything and nothing works

Tags: selenium, screen-scraping

I am running a webscraper and I am not able to click on the third element. I am not sure what to do as I have tried googling and running several types of code.

Below is a screenshot of the html and my code. I need the third element in the list to be clicked on. It is highlighted in the screenshot. I am not sure what to do with the css and data-bind

[image: here is my code. This does not work and I have tried others as well.]
[image: This is the html code. I need the highlighted element in the list to be clicked on. It is the third option]

[here is the code for max bed options. I also need to get the 2 beds just like we did for min bed options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TK6C4.png)

thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to SO! please show the actual code in your question. (not an image) as well as the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the picture the following should work:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@id="bedsMinMaxRangeControl"]//li[@data-value="2"]').click()
```

But we need to see the entire page HTML to give a correct answer.
Also don't forget to use delays/ waits there.
**UPD**
For the new question the code will be:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@id="bedsMinMaxRangeControl"]//ul[contains(@class,"maxBedOptions")]//li[@data-value="2"]').click()
```

Here you should also use the appropriate `data-value` that has values from -1 up to 3

Comment: This worked! How did you know what id it was and that is was a span?

Comment: I also realized that I needed the max bedrooms. If I reuse the code to click on 2 beds for each it does not work. Why is that?

Comment: So the dropdown has a minimum beds and a maximum beds. The code you gave me clicks on minum beds and puts 2 beds down. I would like it to also click on 2 beds for maximum so that it only returns two bedroom apartments!

Comment: In your HTML I see `data-value="4"`. Simple.

Comment: I just put the screenshot for the other list. Won't selecting 4 just put 4 beds as my minimum? What I am trying to do is have 2 beds clicked for minimum then scraper goes and clicks on 2 beds for maximum if that makes sense. Also really appreciate your help!

Comment: This is great!! Thank you so much! I did not know you could use "//" after the brackets to get the elements. I guess for the first answer you could have done the same if you switched the class name. Also, i guess the reason it worked for the first one is because it went to the nearest list?

Comment: You can always use `//` to say "from now" since this is what it actually means, we find some element node and going down from this point. In the first time we had only 1 list of options open so I didn't care about it, while for the second time there were 2 lists of elements with data-value attributes. Or yes, if you do not mention this it goes for the first list / element matching the expression

Comment: Great! Thank you I really appreciate you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `css_selector` with the `data-value` attribute.

```
locator = ".dropdownContent .minBedOptions li[data-value='2']"
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until((EC.element_to_be_clickable, (By.CSS_SELECTOR, locator))).click()
```

I used `WebDriverWait` so make sure to import it...

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you! what does webdriverwait do? is it simular to time.sleep?

Comment: webdriverwait waits until expected condition is fulfilled. here we are waiting until the element becomes clickable. Once Selenium founds this condition fulfilled it immediately continues the flow while time.sleep() simply puts hardcoded pause of X seconds.

Comment: Yup, It's not recommended to use hardcoded time.sleep() delays with Selenium since they cause tests to run much longer time while with expectedconditions you continue exactly at the moment the condition found fulfilled

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a list using li tags as it seems from the shared snap, You could probably write the easiest xpath as :

```
//li[contains(text(), '2 Beds')]
```

and use it like this :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[contains(text(), '2 Beds')]").click()
```

or if you want to use xpath in conjunction of `WebDriverWait`, use it like this :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[contains(text(), '2 Beds')]")))
```

**Import :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Now let's talk about when we do not want to be dependent on `2 Beds` text in XPATH, cause if text changes in the UI, we'd have to change the locator in **Selenium-Python** bindings.

A good way to do is to :

1. Make use of `data-value` attribute : `//li[@data-value = '2']`
2. Make use of ul and li tags : `//ul[contains(@class, 'minBedOptions')/li[@data-value = '2']]`

Comment: This works as well! Thank you! could you explain a little more about the bindings? I tried copying the code in "2." but I got an error